# Getting WiFi SSID to display in php (need GREP help)

Tags: php, regex, grep, wifi, raspbian

I have a need to scan for SSID's and display the results in a php page running in a localhost environment.  I can get this script to run and return a value:

```
    $command= "/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'ESSID'  ";
    $localSSID = exec ($command);
    echo $localSSID;
```

the problem is that it only return the value of the last cell/SSID. for example when I scan in the terminal I get

```
    ESSID:"SSID name X"    
    ESSID:"SSID name Y"    
    ESSID:"SSID name Z"
```

only the last one shows up.

Ideally what I need is just the name of each one to show in a select box as options for users to select.

Anyone have some mad grep regex skills that can offer up any suggestion? I would be very appreciative.

-GWC

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation. Exec only returns the last line. Use the output parameter.

```
$output = array();
exec($command, $output);
```

Now, $output contains a string for every line of output.

Comment: I tried that, but I only got the last line also. I also tried system and passthru, which gets all the data, but I can't do anything with it

Comment: It is not possible that $output only has the last line. It contains all lines of output. Now, if you typed $output=exec($command,$output);, which is NOT what I have above, then $output will have only the last line of output.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, I appreciate the help.  I am relatively new to PHP  but very experienced with ASP, so I am not a total noob.  I looked up references on exec and $output but can't seem to figure this out.  Here is my code 
`  $command= "/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'ESSID'  ";

  $output = array();

  exec($command, $output);

  echo $output;`

but my all I get returned is "Array" (sans quotes).

Comment: $output in an array of values, not a value. You can loop through it with a for loop or a foreach loop. You can dump it using: print_r($output);

Comment: OK, maybe I am a total noob.  I should have thought of that.  Thanks again